# On running my Code on Android Device I get an error as: Execution failed for task ':rn-fetch-blob:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native

I am using the rn-fetch-blob package to download files from url. But on running the code, on android it throws an error as: Execution failed for task ':rn-fetch-blob:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

In terminal: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  Alert,
  ProgressBarAndroid,
  ToastAndroid,
  PermissionsAndroid
} from "react-native";
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";

export default class componentName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      progress: 0,
      loading: false
    };
  }

  actualDownload = () => {
    this.setState({
      progress: 0,
      loading: true
    });
    let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
    RNFetchBlob.config({
      // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
      // this is much more performant.
      path: dirs.DownloadDir + "/path-to-file.png",
      fileCache: true
    })
      .fetch(
        "GET",
        "http://www.usa-essays.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/sample-5-1024x768.jpg",
        {
          //some headers ..
        }
      )
      .progress((received, total) => {
        console.log("progress", received / total);
        this.setState({ progress: received / total });
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          progress: 100,
          loading: false
        });
        ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
          "Your file has been downloaded to downloads folder!",
          ToastAndroid.SHORT,
          ToastAndroid.BOTTOM
        );
      });
  };

  async downloadFile() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: "Storage Permission",
          message: "App needs access to memory to download the file "
        }
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        this.actualDownload();
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          "Permission Denied!",
          "You need to give storage permission to download the file"
        );
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Download Files in Android </Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.downloadFile()} title="Download" />
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <ProgressBarAndroid
            styleAttr="Large"
            indeterminate={false}
            progress={this.state.progress}
          />
        ) : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using react-native 0.60?

Comment: Yes!! I am using rn 0.60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using React Native version 0.59.0 and 0.60.0 was breaking through and giving errors linked to libraries.

Workout: React Native 0.59.9 Just worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

React native 0.60 brings some breaking changes both to Android and iOS.

For the android part the solution (workaround) is explained here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60#androidx-support

```
1) npm install --save-dev jetifier
2) npx jetify
3) npx react-native run-android
4) npx jetify
```

You will have to do step 4 everytime you add a new module or reset your node_modules folder.

Let me know if this solved your issue

Comment: > Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
22 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 20 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  I get this error after running the steps you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For the `RN 0.60.0`, they are giving support for the AndroidX, 
You can use the following command to fix this issue.

```
npm i jetifier
npx jetify
```

You can refer the following doc for the `AndroidX Support`.

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60

Answer (score 0):

Please go to react-native-fetch-blob/android/build.gradle and update these values
compileSdkVersion 23 buildToolsVersion "23.0.3" defaultConfig { minSdkVersion 16 targetSdkVersion 23 versionCode 1 versionName "1.0" }
to these
compileSdkVersion 26 buildToolsVersion "26.0.3" defaultConfig { minSdkVersion 16 targetSdkVersion 26 versionCode 1 versionName "1.0" }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).